# logout doesn't complete

Tags: 20.04

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 dual boot (with windows 10). All works fine for a while, then for no reason logout doesn't complete. I get a black screen and cursor control but no screen to login. My workaround is to reboot and run 'sudo apt-get reinstall -f gdm3'. I can login and out several times but the problem always returns.

I'm using an HP Envy x360 laptop with AMD Razen 4000 series/5

Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks,
ken

Comment: the exhaustive version of what you're attempting is `sudo apt purge gdm3`, because it removes configs. You can also check under user dotfiles (`~/.`) *Then* reinstall. Of course you probably shouldn't be doing either of these while your desktop is running. Boot into recovery to a root shell prompt with networking if you are going to nuke and reinstall any part of the DE.

Comment: Do the reoboot and shutdown commands work ok?

Comment: Yes. I CTRL-ALT-F2 to a terminal and can execute commands.

Comment: Nmath, I did as you suggested and it seemed to help, for a while. It takes longer before it fails but it still fails. I also noticed switching users has much the same problem except I can return to login to the original account.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem, I can now logout and switch users without issue. I do seem to have other problems to investigate.

First there was a very strange issue I discover by accident, system host name. If I did echo $HOSTNAME it would echo the correct host name. Settings/About/Device Name it had my userid. So I changed it to the correct Device Name. I then checked /etc/hosts and it still had my userid. I expected it to be updated but it wasn't. I'm baffled how this happened but it now correct.

The only way I found to fix the logout (and switch user) was to download the current graphic driver update from the AMD website. After installing things were working, however; it appears I have other problems. Checking syslog there are lots of failures. Not sure what installing AMD drivers has done for future updates but I will find out in time. The system doesn't recover from suspend (its now disabled) so perhaps that points to the syslog failures.

This system now boots fast and runs fast!